# FuelPHP Oil Migration not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fuelphp

I have xampp installed and want to get FuelPHP working. Everything seems to work fine, I scaffolded some stuff, that I want to migrate. But I get the error

```
Error - invalid data source name in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 94
```

My db.php looks like this:

```
return array(
  'default' => array(
    'type' => 'pdo',
    'connection' => array(
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pfpg',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'persistent' => false,
      'compress' => false,
    ),
  ),
);
```

I tried it without the 'persistent' and 'compress' before, didn't work. Database name is correct, username too. I also tried it with 'mysql:host=localhost'. I don't get what I did wrong...

If you need more information, ask away!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I configured the wrong db.php file, I didn't know, there was more than one. fuel/app/config/development/db.php was the right file, so it depends on the environment

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who none of this worked make sure of two things

1. there are multiple db.php files `/fuel/app/config/development/db.php`. check environment as @user1978654 mentioned and double check the username and password is correct
2. Make sure `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` exists. In my case I was using `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock` so i needed to create a symlink. [Followed the instructions here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/troubleshooting.html#oil_db_error)

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Go to fuel/app/config/development/db.php put your database name there .. and make sure you un comment the ORM package in fuel\app\config\config.php