# Need to install mysql in php webserver to access remote server mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, installation

I'm trying to setup an separate debian webserver using php-fpm and nginx to access remote mysql server.  So far after I go through several setup from this reference http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

After finish, it works when I remote it from outside using command line mysql -uxxx -p -hxxxxx

Then when I try it on my web server using fuelphp to access the database, it give me error:

> Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 2002 ]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

It seems try to find socket locally to connect to the remote mysql. On the installation of php, I already include apt-get php5-mysql and others except mysql server.

My question: is it possible to setup webserver without have to install mysql in the local machine in order to access mysql on remote? I want to optimize the webserver by separating it from the database.  Thanks

Comment: What are you providing as your mysql host config?

Comment: In fuelphp db config setting, it look like this: return array(
        'default' => array(
                'type' => 'mysql',
                'connection'  => array(
                        'hostname' => '10.130.82.144',
                        'username'   => 'jim',
                        'password'   => 'xxx',
                        'database' => 'xxxx',
                        'persistent' => false
                ),
        ),
);

Comment: can you access your remote mysql like this from your terminal?
mysql -u jim –h 10.130.82.144 –p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not need to install mysql server in your server to access remote mysql. Mysql drivers also come with php preinstalled so you will not need to install those drivers as well. However I am guessing you will need to look in to your mysql host parameter in your app config. It should point to your actual mysql host in remote. May be ip address of the server your remote mysql server is in. And your remote mysql server needs to allow your connections through it as shown in link you provided.

Comment: The setting of remote server side is working fine.  I did try to use terminal to login to it and it works fine.  Now, it's just from the php side that still confuse me.  If you have reference or link about this please share, since I have been googling for days and most people straight setup the server all in one box (LAMP)

Comment: Do you have ssh access to your web server? can you try connecting to your remote mysql server from webserver terminal? Does it work there?

Comment: I guess you will need to install just mysql client and configure it to access remote hosts.

Comment: Also when following the guideline you provided. did you also add access for your webserver ip as defined in STEP5?

Comment: The connection to remote mysql from the webserver is working.  I tested that before hand and also in the webserver I installed php5-mysql too. I'm suspecting the fuelphp framework that I'm using is the cause.  Maybe I will create a simple page of php first to test it.

Comment: Did you check your environment in feul php. refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121120/fuelphp-oil-migration-not-working

Comment: At the end of the day, I finally got it worked after testing around with simple php and fuelphp to connect to the db.  Thx

Comment: henry G - please explain how you got it to work... facing same issue right now. Thanks!